# Как лучше создать набор обьектов в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Ребят есть такой вопрос.Как лучше создать набор одиновых по поведению обьектов но разных по состоянию.То есть основное отличие у них это цвет и количество очков за их убийство.Лучше всего разделить каждый обьект на префаб и создавать их ?.Или может есть варианты получше ?

Comment: Вариантов лучше нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать один скрипт, который будет хранить цвет и количество очков, повесить его на префаб. И запихать их в пулл. А дальше не создавать объекты, а выдергивать их из пула, вбивать в них нужный цвет и очки, и использовать (ну и соответственно при уничтожении не дестроить объект, а возвращать в пул)

Comment: Спасибо.Но я имел ввиду как лучше создать механизм создания разных обьектов. Грубо говоря я должен создавать рандомно шарики с разными спрайтами и за их уничтожение игрок получает некоторое кол-во очков.Я читал что один из вариантов раздедить их на скриптабл обьекты

Comment: Тут две отдельных механизма. Грубо говоря, во время игры нежелательно создавать/удалять большое количество объектов.
В итоге у нас получается, класс А: скриптбл обжект в котором хранятся спрайты. Класс Б: пул с объектами, у которых ест сам геймобжект.
Класс С: Фабрика, которая у которой будет метод BuildBall(string SpriteId, int Score, int xPosition, int yPosition). Который берет из пула объект, достает спрайт по ID, запихивает на объект спрайт/очки/положение, и возращает построенный объект

Comment: Кстати немного еще по теме, тут куски кода обсуждать довольно неудобно, но если хочется поговорить про оптимизацию, у меня в профиле есть ссылка на телеграмм (ага и немного скучающее настроение)), я правда не совсем клиентский программист, но учитывая размеры нашего проекта в работе с юнити тоже что то понимаю))